# making Maxima code run faster (radius of convergence)

Tags: optimization, maxima

I am trying to find the radius of convergence of some Taylor series related to Newton's method applied to the Mandelbrot set.  I have written some Maxima code to this end; the `R` computed is incorrect at least for the first commented case (`1 / inf` instead of `1 / 2`), so I am trying to print some values to see how it behaves numerically.  However Maxima takes too much time (1 second for the first value, 17 seconds for the second, and I gave up waiting for the third).  The performance in the third commented case is even slower.  How might I speed it up?

```
f(c, z) := z^2 + c;
/* h(c) := f(c, f(c, 0)); /* simpler case is much faster */ */
h(c) := ratsimp(f(c, f(c, f(c, 0))) / f(c, 0)); /* polynomial with roots at period 3 components */
/* h(c) := ratsimp(f(c, f(c, f(c, f(c, 0)))) / f(c, f(c, 0))); /* next case is much slower */ */
hh(c) := ratsimp(diff(h(c), c));
N(z) := ratsimp(z - h(z) / hh(z)); /* Newton's method */
M(z) := ratsimp(subst(c = c + z, N(c)) - c); /* perturbed */
for ct in allroots(h(c) = 0) do
(
  print(ct),
  /* coefficient of Taylor series */
  a(n) := at(diff((subst(lhs(ct) = bfloat(rhs(ct)), M(z))), z, n) / factorial(n), z = 0),
  R : 1 / limit(abs(a(n+1)/a(n)), n, infinity), /* radius of convergence */
  print(R), /* prints 1/inf, but this is incorrect at least for the first commented case */
  print(bfloat(1 / abs(a(11)/a(10)))), /* prints after 1 second */
  print(bfloat(1 / abs(a(101)/a(100)))), /* prints after 17 seconds */
  print(bfloat(1 / abs(a(1001)/a(1000)))) /* gave up waiting */
);
```

**EDIT** Correcting the `infinity` vs `inf` confusion, consider the first commented case `h(c) = f(c, f(c, 0)) = c^2 + c`.  Then `M(z) = (z^2 - h(c)) / (2 * z + 2 * c + 1)` which for the root `c = 0` gives `M(z) = z^2 / (1 - (-2 * z))` which is the sum of the geometric series `z^2 (1 + (-2) * z + (-2)^2 * z^2 + ... + (-2)^n z^n + ...)`.  Now the coefficients `a(n) = (-2)^n` so `1 / limit(abs(a(n + 1)/a(n)), n, inf)` should be `1/2`, but Maxima reports a divide by zero:

```
f(c, z) := z^2 + c;
h(c) := f(c, f(c, 0));
hh(c) := ratsimp(diff(h(c), c));
N(z) := ratsimp(z - h(z) / hh(z));
M(z) := ratsimp(subst(c = c + z, N(c)) - c);
for ct in solve(h(c) = 0) do
(
  print(ct),
  a(n) := at(diff((subst(lhs(ct) = bfloat(rhs(ct)), M(z))), z, n) / factorial(n), z = 0),
  invR : limit(abs(a(n+1)/a(n)), n, inf),
  print(abs(a(10+1)/a(10))),
  print(abs(a(100+1)/a(100))),
  print(abs(a(1000+1)/a(1000))),
  print(invR)
);
```

which prints

```
...
c = - 1 
`rat' replaced -1.0B0 by -1/1 = -1.0B0
`rat' replaced -1.0B0 by -1/1 = -1.0B0
2.0b0 
2.0b0 
2.0b0 
0 
c = 0 
`rat' replaced 1.0B0 by 1/1 = 1.0B0
`rat' replaced 1.0B0 by 1/1 = 1.0B0
2.0b0 
2.0b0 
2.0b0 
0
```

I want to evaluate the high order terms of the other examples numerically to see how it behaves, because the limit does not seem to be calculated properly.  But my Maxima code is too slow to make this practical, and while SymPy performs ok for the period 3 (cubic) case (see linked question), for the period 4 (degree 6) it also takes too long.

Comment: Hi Claude, from what I can tell, it looks Maxima needs to compute the nth derivative (and (n + 1)-th derivative) and those derivatives are becoming more and more complicated. Maybe you can see what is the problem by printing out a(n + 1)/a(n) for some small values of n. It looks like abs(a(n + 1)/a(n)) is just a number so at least the final result is simple. Maybe there is a pattern in a(n) or a(n + 1)/a(n) which would make it easy to compute abs(a(n + 1)/a(n)).

Comment: By the way, Maxima distinguishes `infinity` which is complex infinity, from `inf` which is real infinity. For a limit in which a real variable goes to infinity, you want `limit(..., inf)`.

Comment: @RobertDodier I have updated the question with a worked example with a limit calculated by hand.