# result in SymPy depends on sign of a complex number

Tags: sympy

In [making Maxima code run faster (radius of convergence)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67021001/making-maxima-code-run-faster-radius-of-convergence) I had some slow Maxima code, which I managed to rewrite in SymPy which now seems to run in an acceptable time frame and even gives a general term for the series coefficients:

```py
from sympy import limit, roots, simplify, oo
from sympy.abc import c, m, n, z
from sympy.series.formal import rational_algorithm

cs = roots(c ** 3 + 2 * c ** 2 + c + 1, c)
M = (2 * z ** 3 + (3 * c  + 2) * z ** 2) / (3 * z ** 2 + (6 * c + 4) * z + 3 * c ** 2 + 4 * c + 1)
a, independent_term, order = rational_algorithm(M, z, n, full=True)
print(f"a_n = {a}")
r = abs(simplify((a.subs(n, m) / a.subs(n, m + 1))))
print(f"r_m = {r}")
for t in cs:
  print(f"R({t.evalf(5)}) = {limit(r.subs(c, t), m, oo).evalf(5)}")
```

which outputs

```
a_n = c*(-c - 1)**(-n - 1)*(c + 1)**2/2 - (-c - 1/3)**(-n - 1)*(3*c + 1)**2*(3*c + 4)/54
r_m = Abs((3**m*(-(3*c + 1))**(1 - m)*(3*c + 4) - 9*c*(-(c + 1))**(1 - m))/(3**m*(-(3*c + 1))**(-m)*(3*c + 4) - 3*c*(-(c + 1))**(-m)))/3
R(-1.7549) = 0.75488
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/claude/roc.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(f"R({t.evalf(5)}) = {limit(r.subs(c, t), m, oo).evalf(5)}")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/series/limits.py", line 65, in limit
    return Limit(e, z, z0, dir).doit(deep=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/series/limits.py", line 234, in doit
    e = remove_abs(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/series/limits.py", line 220, in remove_abs
    newargs = tuple(remove_abs(arg) for arg in expr.args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/series/limits.py", line 220, in <genexpr>
    newargs = tuple(remove_abs(arg) for arg in expr.args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/series/limits.py", line 224, in remove_abs
    sig = limit(expr.args[0], z, z0, dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/series/limits.py", line 65, in limit
    return Limit(e, z, z0, dir).doit(deep=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/series/limits.py", line 331, in doit
    r = gruntz(e, z, z0, dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/series/gruntz.py", line 672, in gruntz
    r = limitinf(e0, z)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 72, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/series/gruntz.py", line 440, in limitinf
    c0, e0 = mrv_leadterm(e, x)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 72, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/series/gruntz.py", line 524, in mrv_leadterm
    f, logw = rewrite(exps, Omega, x, w)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/series/gruntz.py", line 596, in rewrite
    raise NotImplementedError('Result depends on the sign of %s' % sig)
NotImplementedError: Result depends on the sign of -sign(log(-1/3 - 2*2**(1/3)/(3*(1 - sqrt(3)*I)*(3*sqrt(69) + 25)**(1/3)) - 2**(2/3)*(1 - sqrt(3)*I)*(3*sqrt(69) + 25)**(1/3)/12))
```

It seems the result depends on the sign of a complex number (`-0.057581 - 0.99834*I`), is this a bug in SymPy or something I am doing wrong?  How can I fix it and find the `R` for the complex conjugate root pair?

Comment: what is the sign of a complex number?

Comment: @enzotib I don't know what SymPy means by that either

Comment: Signum [is defined for complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function#Complex_signum). Maybe the `NotImplementedError` exception in this case actually means the complex case was not implemented.